# Xml-attributes in interfaces and abstract classes

Tags: c#, interface, xml-serialization, abstract, custom-attributes

I found something that confused me today:

1. If I have this:

```
public interface INamed
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Named : INamed
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

It gives the following output (Name property serialized as element):

```
<Named>
  <Name>Johan</Name>
</Named>
```

2. If I have this:

```
public abstract class NamedBase
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NamedDerived : NamedBase
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The XmlSerializer throws System.InvalidOperationException

> Member 'NamedDerived.Name' hides inherited member 'NamedBase.Name',
>   but has different custom attributes.

The code I used for serialization:

```
[TestFixture] 
public class XmlAttributeTest
{
    [Test]
    public void SerializeTest()
    {
        var named = new NamedDerived {Name = "Johan"};
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(named.GetType());
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, named);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

My question is:

Am I doing it wrong and if so what is the correct way to use xml attributes in interfaces and abstract classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attributes are not inherited on overriden properties. You need to redeclare them.
Also in your first example the behavior is not the "expected" one as you declared XmlAttribute at the interface level and yet the serialized xml contains the value as an element. So the attribute in the interface is ignored and only info taken from the actual class matters.

Comment: Marking this as answer, guess my real question is why it is allowed to declare Attributes on interfaces and abstract classes. Maybe its just a limitation in how fine grained the control of attribute usage is.

Comment: well you can declare them wherever you like as long as the code that reads them back is aware of that. In this case the serializer would have to check the class definition and then all implemented interfaces for attributes. As for attribute usage; it is defined in this case as [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.ReturnValue)]. Property means any property and ClassOnlyProperty does not exist as a possible restriction (i'm not sure if it would be all that useful).

Comment: As with anything at some point you need to read the documentation. Not every behavior can be described as a syntax restriction and nor it should be

Answer (score 7):

I think you should xmlignore your abstract class property

```
public abstract class NamedBase
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NamedDerived : NamedBase
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This helped me immensely; for some reason the serializer wants to explicitly process the base class as well which I specifically intended to be unaware of the underlying storage mechanism...

Comment: I was trying to use '<PropertyName>Specified' property with XmlIgnore attribute to ignore serialization of empty lists and '<PropertyName>Specified' was honored only if the abstract property is attributed with 'XmlIgnore'