# XMLIgnore-attribute on derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, xml-serialization

I have a property in a base-class marked with the `XmlIgnore`-attribute. When I derive this class and do NOT override (as opposed to [Xml-attributes in interfaces and abstract classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13182452/2528063)) this property, is this attribute preserved so that the derived class has the property with also `XmlIgnore`-attribute or do I have to override the property in order to reset the attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your derived class does not override the property with the XmlIgnore attribute set, that property will be duly ignored when serializing.

If your derived class *does* override the property, and forgets to set the XmlIgnore attribute, that property will be duly serialized.

Sample code to show the behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[Serializable]
public abstract class myBaseClass
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual bool aBoolean { get; set; }

    public int anInt { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class myDerivedClass : myBaseClass
{
    public string derivedString { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class overrideXmlIgnore : myBaseClass
{
    // no XmlIgnore
    public override bool aBoolean
    {
        get
        {
            return base.aBoolean;
        }
        set
        {
            base.aBoolean = value;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // build array of types we can serialize/deserialize
        // uses Linq and Reflection namespaces
        Type[] derivedTypes = (from lAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                               from lType in lAssembly.GetTypes()
                               where typeof(myBaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(lType)
                               select lType).ToArray();

        // build a test object to serialize with XMLIgnore still used
        myDerivedClass m = new myDerivedClass();
        m.aBoolean = true; // this property is ignored by default
        m.derivedString = "test";

        // set a file path to serialize to
        string testFilePath = "C:\\temp\\test.xml";

        // serialzie the object
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myBaseClass), derivedTypes);
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(testFilePath);
        x.Serialize(sw, m);
        sw.Close();

        // deserialize the object
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(testFilePath);
        myBaseClass deserializedObject = (myBaseClass)x.Deserialize(sr);
        sr.Close();

        // check the object's properties
        // aBoolean is false, even though the serialized object m set it to true, because of XmlIgnore
        Console.WriteLine("aBoolean = " + deserializedObject.aBoolean.ToString());

        // repeat process for the derived class that overrides and does not set XmlIgnore
        overrideXmlIgnore o = new overrideXmlIgnore();
        o.aBoolean = true;
        sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(testFilePath);
        x.Serialize(sw, o);
        sw.Close();
        sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(testFilePath);
        deserializedObject = (myBaseClass)x.Deserialize(sr);

        // check the object's properties
        // aBoolean is true, as we no longer XmlIgnore
        Console.WriteLine("aBoolean = " + deserializedObject.aBoolean.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: actually there seems to be a bug in XmlSerializer - it doesn't respect [XmlIgnore] at hidden (reintroduced with new) or overriden property - see https://dotnetfiddle.net/W9zCSm

Comment: Just filled-in a bug report here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44701. 
The other way around seems to work ok, aka  if you don't have [XmlIgnore] at descendant's reintroduced/overriden property though ancestor had such attribute, the property is serialized ok

Comment: a workaround is probably to have the subclass produce XmlAttributeOverrides via a helper method and then when serializing, pass those too to the XmlSerializer - see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d70a9b9-0546-478b-8fd1-becee107106a/xmlserializer-fails-when-trying-to-serialize-hidden-property-with-xmlignore

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis: unless I am missing something, "doesn't respect `XmlIgnore` at hidden or overridden property" is just re-describing the behavior explained in the answer.  As for it being a bug or not, it's hard for me to comment.  Docs for `XmlIgnore` and `XmlSerializer` are not so clear on what the intended behavior should be for derived classes.  (It also might matter if the 'main' type in the first constructor parameter for the serializer is the base type, or the derived type.  In the answer, the base type is the one used, as that's a common pattern when serializing a base type.)

Comment: What I observed is that when using the descendent class type and instance with the XMLSerializer, you can override stuff to add but not to hide. See a workaround for that at https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bvbi0N that also shows how to inject comments (based on techniques suggested on SO). Other strange bugs also bit me in the way (mentioning them there), like WCF choking when you use XmlAnyElement to inject a comment, but haven't specified a node name at the XmlAnyElement attribute